# Node-RED: associate HTTP request and response

Tags: node-red

I am using (trying to use) the standard http-request node to query a website. Unfortunately, the site's answer does not include the original request information. Since there may be several requests running, how can I associate the request and response correctly?

Maybe I am just using it wrong, or I don't get it right? In a classical programming environment handles would be used for this.

2nd, the request is derived from another processing task, it is used to augment existing information. I assume I have to use the context store to temporarily store information until the request is finished by a response?

(Background: I request a list of place names in a regular interval via HTTP – that's easy. In order to show them on a map, I need to request a reverse geocoding service for each place to get coordinates. Caching places that were already resolved is also desirable; using the (persistent) context store would provide for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http-request` node will output the same `msg` that was passed into it.

e.g. if you pass in a `msg` object that looks like:

```
{
  topic: "foo",
  payload:{ 
    name: "Ben"
  },
  counter: 99
}
```

And the http-request node is set to pass the msg.payload as arguments to the request URL, (assuming the http server return "Hello [name]") the output `msg` object will look like:

```
{
  topic: "foo",
  payload:"Hello Ben",
  counter: 99
}
```

As you can see the `topic` and `counter` fields have been left intact. You can use this approach to attach what ever meta data you want to the `msg` as it passes through the flow. If you have state information that is not directly related to a give `msg`, then the context is the right place to store it.

All well behaved nodes should  always output an updated version of the input `msg`.

Comment: Thank you! The "http request" node passing the topic without change is the missing link I was looking for. I did not find any information about that in the node's info text.

Comment: It's not documented explicitly as it's expected for all nodes (some 3rd party nodes do not do this, but you should raise it as a bug if you find one)